# What is the difference between these two paths in urlpatterns?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('job', jobs.views.home, name='home'),
    path('job/', include('jobs.urls')),
]
```

What is the difference between the two paths? When should I use jobs.views.home and when should I use the include()

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

Answer (score 3):

I'm a new django-user so i will try to answer maybe i'm wrong.

```
path('job', jobs.views.home, name='home')
```

will call the home function that you defined in views.py file of the API jobs

```
path('job/', include('jobs.urls))
```

will include the file urls.py in your job API.

In your urls.py , you should have     `path('', jobs.views.home, name='home')`
to call the home function of your views.py file